# Java double value matching NaN

Tags: java, nan

I have a question if there is a value in Java that is equivalent to `Double.NaN`.
It is common knowledge that `Double.NaN` is equivalent to `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)`.
I tried this in C++:

```cpp
long d = (long)0x7ff8000000000000L;
cout << setprecision(308) << *((double*)&d) << endl;
```

and recieved this number: `1.7913854515396173439813246875759771148370355414969747463437939834712133067539348971091007957318376384187247712070435161526222960236442304023361887799416099781498803833913104211684781256626064276104912473088500848240020138295465213393610297503047186864315005421110542290050185011298999959710557864144337912608e-307`. But I tried this in Java and it didn't work. Is there a double equivalent to `Double.NaN` in Java?

Answer (score 2):

In Java we have the constant [`Double.NaN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#NaN), which according to the documentation is the same as `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)`. Why do you expect it to be equal to C++'s representation of `NaN`?

Your C++ conversion seems faulty, and also according to the docs of [`Double.longBitsToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)) there can be differences in the bit patterns returned, even if it's IEEE 754 compliant. Don't depend on such low-level implementation details for your code.

Answer (score 0):

NaN is not a number, therefore you must not attempt to perform arithmetic on it, for example, comparing it to another number.